# Kubuntu: zsh and firefox in conflict

Tags: firefox, zsh, kubuntu

I have a fresh install of Kubuntu on my notebook. I have downloaded zsh through apt and changed the default shell to zsh from bash, using `chsh -s`. I have not downloaded `.oh-my-zsh`, and I have not edited any of the startup files. When I log out and then back in, the web browser Firefox is not accessible in any of the normal ways:

-icon is gone from the desktop panel

-icon and option is gone from the application launcher

-Krunner does not recognize Firefox as a command

I am able to find the executable in a terminal: `which firefox` returns `/snap/bin/firefox` (same as when using bash). However, when I run `firefox` in the terminal with zsh, it opens a guest browser and my account information is not available.

These problems disappear when I reset the default shell to bash. As far as I can tell, Firefox is the only affected application.

System information:

Kubuntu: 5.15.0-58-generic

Firefox: 109.0

x86-64; intel i7-6700HQ

I do not know where or how to access any relevant log files; if you know of any particular logs you'd like to see, please direct me on how to find them for you.

I've been using linux casually for 5 or so years; on my old machine (Acer), I ran this same setup, though with Chrome, and experienced no similar or analogous problems.

NB: I have been using Linux for a while, but casually; I can get around and sort out problems with google's help, but I am a novice.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone looking for the solution: I have found it [here](https://www.chrisrmiller.com/zsh-and-snaps-integration-for-kde-and-others/).
The problem is missing paths to snap applications. It is fixed by adding the line below to the end of the file `/etc/zsh/zprofile`, as root:

`emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).